# Create UICollectiionViewCell based on UIView

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to have a UICollectionView that holds different UIViews as its cells. Is this possible or do I have to make them UICollectionViewCells?

Comment: create cells that wrap each unique view

Comment: @Scriptable Do you have a good example of this?

Comment: not to hand... its fairly easy to do, I'll give you a basic example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an objective-c example, but you should be able to get the concept from the code example below.

An example how you can create a cell that wraps a UIView and is more reusable

```
class ProfileView: UIView {
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var name: UILabel!
}

class ProfileCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     let profileView = ProfileView() 

     init() {
         super.init()
         configureConstraints()
     }

     func configureConstraints() {
        // use a handy extension you've already built
        contentView.addSubView(profileView)
        profileView.pinToEdges(of: contentView)
     }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let row = self.objects[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "someId" for: indexPath) as? ProfileCollectionViewCell
    cell?.profileView.imageView.image = row["image"]
    cell?.profileView.name.text = row["name"]
    return cell
}
```

note: you may need to manage 'resetting the cells state' before it gets reused with something like:

```
override prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse() 

    profileView.imageView.image = nil
    profileView.name.text = ""
}
```

Comment: So the idea is to create a UICollectionViewCell and add the real content in a subview? It feels like cheating but i might be right :)

Comment: pretty much yeah... but this way it's reusable in the collection view and will give better performance

Comment: Thanks I will try this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `UICollectionViewCell`s. `UICollectionView` don't accept `UIView`s.

What you can do is create a generic `UICollectionViewCell` that can embed any `UIView`.
The reason is because collection view cells have specific composition for layout and recycling.

Also, you add child in your `UIView` directly on the view itself, collection view cells have a `contentView`, like `UITableViewCell`s.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to it this way as you lose the reusability and caching that comes with the dequeueing system. by adding/removing views to a generic cell the only thing that is reused is an empty cell.

Comment: Of course the views itselves have to be managed properly, don't recreate them on the fly 